# Why do I get the same hash for different pdf files using crypto-js?

Tags: angular, pdf, hash, cryptojs

I upload a pdf file and use crypto-js to create a hash from it, but I always get the same hash no matter which file I upload. Also, the hash I get does not correspond to the hash I get from the file when I use an online tool to create the hash.
I have the same issue with txt files and if I load the files from the assets directory. I also tried other libraries and have the same issue.

What I'm I missing?

I use Angular 6. Here is how I do it.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import sha256 from 'crypto-js/sha256';

@Component({
  selector: 'ct-sign-page',
  templateUrl: './sign-page.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class SignPageComponent {
  public file: File;

  public fileChange(event): void {
    this.file = event.target.files[0];
    const hash = sha256(this.file);
    console.log(hash.toString());
  }
}
```

Update:
This is what I get if I log this.file before I create the hash.

```
File
lastModified: 1603727900290
lastModifiedDate: Mon Oct 26 2020 16:58:20 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
name: "sample.pdf"
size: 3028
type: "application/pdf"
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: File
```

Comment: Maybe it could help when you print out "this.file" after the line "this.file = event.target.files[0];"

Comment: @MichaelFehr see update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to read the file and create a hash based on its content.

Though I'm not sure why it is generating the same hash but I guess it is related to some internal methods like `toString()` which return same string for any `event.target.files[0]`.

```js
fileChange = (event) => {
  var file = event.target.files[0];

  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  
  fileReader.addEventListener('loadend', (evt) => {
  
    if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {
      const hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(fileReader.result);
      console.log(hash.toString());
    }
    
  });


  fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" #fileInput onchange="fileChange(event)" />
```